# Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be the fractional parts of $(44-\sqrt 2017)^{2017}$ and $(44+ \sqrt 2017)^{2017}$ respectively. Then $F_1+F_2$ lies between?

Tags: fractional-part

The fractional part of a real number x is $x –[x]$, where $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x.$ Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be the fractional parts of $(44-\sqrt 2017)^{2017}$ and $(44+ \sqrt 2017)^{2017}$ respectively. Then $F_1+F_2$ lies between?

a) $0$ and $0.45$
b) $0.45$ and $0.9$
c) $0.9$ and $1.35$
d) $1.35$ and $1.8$

Any trick to answering the question fast is appreciated (like analyzing the options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$|44-\sqrt{2017}|\lt1$$
so the absolute value (and hence fractional part) of the first term tends to zero when it is raised to a large exponent. Also we have for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$(44-\sqrt{2017})^n+(44+\sqrt{2017})^n\in\mathbb{N}$$
Hence the fractional part due to the second term must tend to one when raised to a large exponent in order for the above fact to be true. This leads to the conclusion that $F_1+F_2\approx 1$ for large $n$ and actually tends towards the value of $1$ when $n\to\infty$. This means that the only possible answer would be c).

Comment: If $(44+\sqrt{2017})^{2017}=a_1+b_1\sqrt{2017}=n_1+F_1$, then $(44-\sqrt{2017})^{2017}=a_1-b_1\sqrt{2017}=n_2+F_2$. So $F_1+F_2=2a_1-n_1-n_2$ is an integer. As clearly $0<F_i<1$, it follows that $F_1+F_2=1$ **exactly**.

Comment: Yes, sorry, what you have written is correct. I don't think I should edit my answer because it would be to effectively change it to what you have written here.